# creating distributable windows python module with f2py

Tags: python, windows, gfortran, f2py

I have written some code with python and f2py, mostly using linux. This all works fine, but now I would like to share this with windows users, so I am trying to make a module that is distributable to users who don't necessarily have gfortran or gcc. I've got access to a windows xp box, am using mingw with gfortran. I can compile and use the module on that machine, but on other machines the pyd created seems to require the dll's libgcc and libgfortran. Here is an example from http://www.scipy.org/F2PY_Windows:

```
subroutine hello ()
   write(*,*)'Hello from Fortran90!!!'
end subroutine hello
```

Compile with

```
python c:\path\to\python\scripts\f2py.py -c \
       --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 \
        -lmsvcr71 -m foo foo.f90
```

This works as expected on the machine I compiled it with, but if I copy it to another machine, I get

```
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Using dependency walker, I see it cannot find the dll's for libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and libgfortran-3.dll. Is it possible to create a pyd that I can distribute without assuming the user has gcc and gfortran? I'm using python2.7 on both machines, both 32bit. One is xp, the other windows 7.

Comment: Why not redistribute mingw's libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and libgfortran-3.dll with the pyd?

Comment: Well, eventually I would like to use setup.py, to build a binary for the module. I don't know how I would add the dll's to the binary.

Comment: Use distutils package_data or data_files (http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html)

Comment: Ok, I think my problem is the compiler I was using. If instead of using the mingw compilers, you download gfortran from, for example, [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries) and make sure this is in your path first, then compile it seems to work ok. This is  pretty much the instructions on [link](http://www.scipy.org/F2PY_Windows) so if I'd had read that properly it would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to including the `libgcc` and `libgfortran` dlls in the package, it should be possible to link against the static versions of these libraries, provided they are available in your build of MinGW. (At least, I assume it is. I have no experience with Python or pyds, but it is possible for regular executables and dlls.)

Look at the `-static` option for linking, or if you need more control `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libgfortran`.

Comment: This is the method I've had success with. MinGW gcc (with gfortran) uses the shared libs by default.