# Using F2py for creating python module in windows

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I am trying to create python module in windows 7 using f2py command

```
This is my test FORTRAN code :

 subroutine foo(a)
 integer a
 print*,"Hello from Fortan foo"
 print*,"a=",a
 call goo(a)
 end

 subroutine goo(b)
 integer b
 integer c
 c=b+10
 print*,"Hello from goo"
 print*,"c=",c
 end
```

I am using command :

> f2py -c -m test hello.f --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32

With this I could create test.pyd which I could import and use in my computer but when I tried the same module in another computer it gives an error message as

> Import Error:DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

How can I solve this issue. I got one link which describe about the same problem like mine

> [creating distributable windows python module with f2py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756212/creating-distributable-windows-python-module-with-f2py)
>   But still I could not figure out how I can solve this issue. Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Is this the same as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112165/using-module-built-using-f2py ?

Comment: yes its the same question, but i could not solve my problem with those answers. I would like to know in detail about this problem. Or this there any other alternative of f2py ?

Comment: Do not duplicate answers here, edit them!